# I have a problem when I want to insert a sql text in my phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

Sorry if my English is bad: I'm French ^^

I want insert that but I can't because I have an error

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `moneysafes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `safe` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `money` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `transactions` text NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

error:

> #1101 - BLOB 'transactions' cannot have a default value

Anyone have a solution please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the line

```
`transactions` text NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
```

to

```
`transactions` text NOT NULL,
```